# Laravel 9 -CORS

Tags: php, laravel, cors, laravel-9

I was trying do accept CORS in my Laravel-9 API, But I'm`having some troubles

Request work normally whe I use insomnia
[image]

But when I try AJAX it didn't work
[image]

cors.php is configure in this way:
[image]

Kernel:
[image]

Route on api.php:

```
Route::post('/agendamentos/usuariosDisponiveis', [AgendamentosController::class, 'usuariosDisponiveis']);
```

I want to resolve CORS error